# Can bibtex print a bibliography without including [LABELS]?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

If I have write, for example, `\cite{ahu61}` with the following `.bib` entry

```
@article{ahu61,
   author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
   title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
   journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
   volume={8},
   year = 1961,
   pages = {175-191}
 }
```

Then the `\printbibliography` command will generate something like this:

[image]

I want to get rid of the label circled in red. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this a `biblatex` (there is a big difference) question? Besides, always provide a full minimal example that others can copy and run without having to add anything.

Comment: `bibstyle=author-year`?

Comment: Your question is not clear: Can you add please what you want to have? A sorted list for authors? There are different bibliography styles and which one you should use depends on what you want how your bibliography should look ...

Comment: I want the area inside the red circle to be blank. The contents of the citations themselves are fine.

Comment: Please provide a comprehensive [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Also it strikes me as very odd to use a alphabetic scheme and then render it unusable to the reader because you make it infinitely harder to identify a work if you drop the label in the bibliography.